# DateTime issue with vb and mdb

Tags: sql, ms-access, datetime

I am working on an old software that uses a .mdb database.

I have succeeded in setting up a connection to the database and i can run sql queries just fine when it comes to preprogrammed queries like this one :

`SELECT COUNT(*) AS test FROM shifts WHERE EmpId = '2' AND DateOpen <= '3/28/2007'`

Moving on, i replaced the 2 with an expression depending on the user selection like so

`Employees(employe.SelectedIndex)`

This worked fine too.

Now, when i tried to replace the date with `startDate.Value.ToShortDateString` i started facing many conversion problems and i finally had something that worked so my where clause became like this :

`WHERE EmpId = '" & Employees(employe.SelectedIndex) & "' AND DateDiff('d', DateOpen, '" & endDate.Value.ToShortDateString & "') <= 0`

Now i chose the same date that was in the query above, the query runs with no problems but surprisingly i got a null result, which doesn't make any sense to me because the query with the values already there returned a count of 2.

I used some debugging output to make sure the query is properly being generated and i got the same query as above when i select the date.

If you have any idea why this is not working or have any hints on the proper way to do it, i would appreciate all your input.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you put the `datediff` comparison into your "preprogrammed" query and see if that returns what you expect?

Comment: toShortDateString?  Doesn't look like VB6 to me, what object has this method?

Comment: DateDiff in an Access query accepts (string, date, date), you have `DateDiff('d', DateOpen, '" & endDate & "')` (ignoring the extras), which is `string, date, string`, try `DateDiff('d', DateOpen, #" & endDate & "#)` You may run into locale problems, in which case you will have to format enddate to year, month, day.

Comment: @TimLehner yes i tried adding the adding the datediff and i get the same thing 

BobRiemersma my mistake, ill recheck the tags

Remou Thanks, didn't know i could do that, ill give it a shot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using BETWEEN in the query, and with params the query works like a charm!

```
WHERE (DateOpen BETWEEN @DStart AND @DEnd)
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you avoid using formatted strings when dealing with dates in MS Access and VBA.

A tip: VBA and MS Access store dates as double values, the integral part represents the date (days since January 1st., 1900), and the decimal part represents the time (in fractions of day). E.G.: June 20th, 2012, 05:57 is stored as the number 41080.2408.

Instead of using formatted strings, you may use the double value to compare dates just as you compare any pair of numbers. If the values are stored in fields with the "Date/Time" type, you can just use `CDbl()` to convert the date to a double value, and then compare it with another double.

This has worked for me. Hope this helps you.